# Rss Parser check internet connection and display a message

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser, reachability

I'm thinking about check the internet connection and display a message if here is not connection, so now I have a TableView, And I think I have to delete or replace this table view or show only one cell and display a message like "There is no internet connection", so first I added a file to check connection so I did this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.title = "ACTUALITÉS"

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

        self.beginParsing()

        } else {
            //Here I'm gonna do something and display an image
        }

    }



    @IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(delegate)
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"url..."))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        tableView!.reloadData()
    }

    //XMLParser Methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
            dscrptn = NSMutableString()
            dscrptn = ""
            url = NSURL()
            urlString = NSMutableString()
            urlString = ""
        } else {
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = "No connection"
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
            }
            if !dscrptn.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(dscrptn, forKey: "dscrptn")
            }
            if !urlString.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(urlString, forKey: "urlString")
            }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("title") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            date.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("description") {
            dscrptn.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("link") {
            urlString.appendString(string)
        }
    }

    //Tableview Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let trimUrl = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("urlString") as! String

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: trimUrl.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))!)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        return basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }


    func basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> ActuTblCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ActuTblCell

        setTitleForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        setDateForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        setDescriptionForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func setTitleForCell(cell:ActuTblCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        cell.titleActuCell?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
    }

    func setDateForCell(cell:ActuTblCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        let dateString = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String
        if let dateAdded = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))
        {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            cell.dateActuCell?.text = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateAdded))"
        }
        //cell.dateActuCell?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String
    }

    func setDescriptionForCell(cell:ActuTblCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        cell.descriptionActuCell?.text = (posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("dscrptn") as! NSString as String).stripHTML()
    }
}

let     htmlReplaceString   :   String  =   "<[^>]+>"

extension NSString {
    func stripHTML() -> NSString {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(htmlReplaceString, withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: self.length)) as NSString
    }
}


extension String {
    func stripHTML() -> String {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(htmlReplaceString, withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
    }
}
```

I know how to check connection but here I don't know what is the better solution and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve it is called empty states. Ideas for empty states can be found [www.pttrns.com](http://pttrns.com/ios-patterns?scid=30). In your case empty state is shown when no network connection. Another case could be when network connection available, but *post* array have zero items after the parsing the content (XML/JSON).

I would recommend you to use 3rd party code:

- [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet#dznemptydataset) (objective-c)
- [StatefulViewController](https://github.com/aschuch/StatefulViewController) (Swfit)

Another way would be to set background image to the tableView. I want to notice that background image should be the size as device screen. You can do it like that:

```
let tempImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage"))
tempImageView.frame = self.tableView.frame
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```